# Wordpress and URL re-writing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How do I re-write in wordpress, in the .htaccess file?

I'm trying to change the structure of a plugin's url from

`mysite.com/user-favorites?user=joebloggs`

to

`mysite.com/user-favorites/joebloggs`

The `user-favorites` is a page (with a template to call the plugin) in wordpress, so it would seem logical to ignore the slug of `user-favorites` and in .htaccess write `/index.php?p=23&user=joebloggs` with the post ID instead of the wordpress slug.

So far I've got

```
RewriteRule ^user-favorites/(.*) /index.php?user=$1&p=23 [NC,L]
```

(full file: http://pastebin.com/GFWnKLEA)

But with this, it redirects to `mysite.com/user-favorites` when I visit:
`mysite.com/user-favorites/joebloggs`

Maybe i'm going the wrong way about it, is there a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user-favorites/([^/]*)$ /user-favorites?user=$1 [L]
```

Can you please try this and let me know if it works. ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. It stays on 'mysite.com/user-favorites/joebloggs' when typed in, but says page not found.

Comment: It seems to me that @aghoshx is on the right track though.  I apologize that I can't be of much more assistance, but perhaps working with his `.htaccess` rules you can get something that works.

Comment: The 404 is because WordPress doesn't understand the URL structure since this wasn't written by it - There may be some plugins for editing the permalink structures, alternatively you could hack the 404.php in your theme folder to respond to this query - its a very crude hack.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going under to Settings --> Permalinks inside the WordPress Dashboard?

Comment: Hmm, to do what?.. It's kinda a custom thing I want done, don't think I'll find an option for it.

Comment: Try that. Has enough options there that should help you in creating .htaccess file.

Comment: I wasn't sure if those settings would rewrite the URL for that plugin, I figured that the Permalink settings were worth a shot.  Do you currently have permalinks enabled?

Comment: Yep permalinks enabled, really not sure where to go from here.